# dojocharts issues in responsive

Tags: css, dojo, dojox.charting, dojox.mobile

I am trying to generate a responsive dojocharts for mobile and tablets.

Here I had already trying though media queries through CSS. but its not working properly.

So anyone please suggest  me how can I make my dojo chart responsive.

Below is my example for dojo responsive chart.but not working.

```
 <script>
 require(["dojox/charting/Chart",
"dojox/charting/plot2d/Pie",
"dojox/charting/action2d/Highlight",
"dojox/charting/action2d/MoveSlice",
"dojo/fx/easing",
"dojox/charting/action2d/Tooltip",
"dojox/charting/themes/MiamiNice",
"dojox/charting/widget/Legend",
"dojo/ready"
],
function(Chart, Pie, Highlight, MoveSlice, easing, Tooltip, MiamiNice, Legend, ready) {
ready(function() {
    var chartTwo = new Chart("chartTwo");
    chartTwo.setTheme(MiamiNice)
        .addPlot("default", {
            type: Pie,
            font: "normal normal 11pt Tahoma",
            fontColor: "black",
            animate: {
                duration: 1000,
                easing: easing.cubicIn
            },
            labelOffset: -30,
            radius: 150
        }).addSeries("Series A", [{
            "y": 101,
            67,
            "text": "INDIA",
            "tooltip": "INDIA"
        }, {
            "y": 339.86,
            "text": "USA",
            "tooltip": "USA"
        }, {
            "y": 329.73,
            "text": "UK",
            "tooltip": "UK"
        }, {
            "y": 953.96,
            "text": "UAE",
            "tooltip": "UAE"
        }]);
    var anim_a = new MoveSlice(chartTwo, "default");
    var anim_b = new Highlight(chartTwo, "default");
    var anim_c = new Tooltip(chartTwo, "default");
    chartTwo.render();
    var legendTwo = new Legend({
        chart: chartTwo
    }, "legendTwo");
});
});
</script>

 <body class="claro">
  <div id="chartTwo" style="width: 600px; height: 350px;"></div>
 <div id="legendTwo"></div>
```

So kindly request to everbody and also dojo community please suggest for this question for responsive dojocharts.

Comment: This isn't a dojo community. Please show us what have you done so far so we can help you.

Comment: @MehulMohan..Here i am using this code for responsive through javascript    ' var screenwidth = window.innerWidth;
 var pieradius = 100;
 var pielabeloffset =4;
 var piestartangel =120;
 if(screenwidth <600){pieradius = 90; pielabeloffset = 10;piestartangel= 60;} ' and also media queries like ' media screen and (max-width:600px){.chartDiv{width:100%}'

Comment: @MehulMohan.suggest me how can i make my chart responsive.